# Retrieving data from database and increment by one

Tags: java, mysql

I am trying to retrieve a data (ID No.) from a database (MySQL) and add it by one. However, when I try to put this code below, when I try to build it, the form doesn't show up. But when I try to remove the `Connection cn` line, the form with finally show up. I had another project with this code it it worked perfectly fine. I'm not sure why its not working on this one.

```
public Abstract() throws Exception {

    Connection cn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/user?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull","root","");
    initComponents();

    Statement st = null;
    ResultSet rs;

    try {
        String sql = "SELECT ID from bidding_abstractofprices";
        st = cn.prepareStatement(sql);
        rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
        while(rs.next()){
            int id = Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("ID")) + 1;
            lblTransacID.setText(String.valueOf(id));
        }
    }catch (Exception ex){
    }
}
```

Comment: Do not suppress an exception: `catch (Exception ex){ }` print something out of it (i.e. `ex.getMessage()`). Maybe it will give you an idea what's going on there... Did you try to debug your code and see how your loop is going?

Answer (score 0):

What it looks like you are trying to do is to get the **ID** field value from the last record contained within the **bidding_abstractofprices** Table contained within your Database and then increment that **ID** value by one (*please correct me if I'm wrong*). I don't care why but I can easily assume. Here is how I might do it:

```
public Abstract() throws Exception {
    // Allow all your components to initialize first.
    initComponents(); 

    Connection cn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/user?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull","root","");
    Statement st = null;
    ResultSet rs;

    try {
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM bidding_abstractofprices ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1;";
        st = cn.prepareStatement(sql);
        rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
        int id = 0; 
        while(rs.next()){
            id = rs.getInt("ID") + 1;
        }
        lblTransacID.setText(String.valueOf(id));
        rs.close();
        st.close();
        cn.close();
    } catch (SQLException ex) { 
         ex.printStackTrace(); 
    }
}
```